# How to integrate Facebook AccountKit with Parse Server

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

The new Facebook [AccountKit](https://developers.facebook.com/products/account-kit), looks like a great way to add passwordless authentication to a mobile app.

[Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) is fast becoming a de-facto choice for mobile back-ends.

Is adding AccountKit support underway somewhere with Parse Server? If so where?  Where should I look or ask? (*Yes, I've tried!*)

Any suggestions for how to get started?  E.g. is it possible to add to the [existing oauth](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth) support in Parse Server?

Just trying to make sure that this doesn't exist somewhere obvious already and/or that efforts aren't underway before I jump in...  (*or, possibly, that this is just a dumb idea and that's why I can't find it!*)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for being late

Yes its possible you can use a new parse server module called "parse-server-accountkit-auth"

In the parse-server-example folder run

```
npm install -S parse-server-accountkit-auth
```

This will make install this module in node_modules folder. Don't change anything in the module.

Edit the index.js file in parse-server-example and configure ParseServer with oauth, you can find this in parse server [docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/OAuth)

Then use this code where you are defining your data (e.g in your index.js of parse-server-example)

```
oauth: {
  accountkit: {
    module: 'parse-server-accountkit-auth',
    appSecret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET'
  },},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at this and mark it as the answer assuming it all works ok. (Might be a while though as I'm currently buried in another project. Will come back to it though!)